# JSON and free web hosting

Tags: php, json, web-hosting

I write a litle site and use Json.

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
 header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 echo '{"json":"data"}';
```

When I receive json the web hosting add to it some code and I receive the response

```
{"json":"data"}
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

and that get error of course.

**But I need **

```
{"json":"data"}
```

What is wrong, how joomla or wordpress work on the same free hosting, they also use json.

Comment: which error? where's your code? what's your question?

Comment: Your hosting software should check that your `Content-Type` is HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 000webhost and for security reasons they add a statistics code to check if your site is active and not fake. To remove it, please visit https://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php and disable the statistics code from your site.

Comment: Thanks I will try and I think it will help me. but when I install joomla I also not disabled analytics, but joomla work well. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I never worked with joomla :( And btw, accept my answer if it helps you.

Comment: @user3274144 Because everything Joomla output is HTML pages. What your hosting adds is valid HTML comments and scripts so in the end you get valid HTML. But when hosting adds this to JSON, you get something that is not valid JSON. If this string is added to images, images, by their standard, still remain valid. Not sure what happens with scripts and CSS...

Comment: @George Sovetov I know that I get invalid json, but joomla and wordpress also, I think use json, and why with joomla and wordpress I not see that problem?

Comment: @user3274144 Try to find those requests and their responses with developer tools in your browser. Compare their headers with actual headers of your responses. Make sure that this hosting doesn't treat Joomla and Wordpress sites in special way.

Comment: or joomla and wordpress don't use json or xml?